# QGIS Composer map scale turns incorrect after working properly

Tags: print-composer, scale, qgis-2.18, windows-10

I am working on a project with several QGIS Project files. I have one Project file with certain layers and settings which I copy every time I need to create a new Project file within this work. I have used a composer template to print maps with identical framing from these different Project files. It has worked fine for long, until these several issues appeared at once:

1. I loaded once again the composer template but the map in the template appears blank, and does not reappear by Refreshing the View.
2. I can add a new map frame to the template, but the map scale appears incorrect. For example I set the scale to 1:10'000, but it gives me a map with a scale of 1:5000. Scale bar equals to the scale of the map, not the setup in scale bar properties. There is only one map frame in composer.
3. I create a completely new composer inside the current Project file, but the scale issue remains.
4. Also these issues appear in all the composers which I had created earlier in other Project files under this work.

However the scale problem disappears when I create a completely new Project file. It seems that the root of the problem is in the Project file - but where to start looking for the reason? I have not changed any setup in Project file, at least not consciously. I didn't find similar issue from earlier Questions.

I am working with QGIS 2.18.11 in Windows 10 Pro. Since I started this work I have updated QGIS twice, but I am not sure at which point this issue appeared.

Comment: Have you set the page size in the 'Composition' settings or only in "Page Setup"?

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: Michel Stuyts: I assume your comment was related to the scale bar scale issue that was in my original question that was put on hold. Thank you for your comment, I had changed the page size only in Composition settings. However Page Setup didn't solve this issue yet, but I keep looking for ways to fix it. My main suspect is the printer's setup so I left out the scale bar issue from edited question trying to narrow down the question.

Comment: PolyGeo: I edited my question. Is it still too broad? I believe all issues described here are essential for solving the cause of the problem. I hope my question is better defined now.

Comment: If you have two or more maps on composer,  you have to check which map the scale bar shows to you. Map0, map1, map2...

Comment: nagib: Thanks for reminding me about this essential detail: no I only have one map on a composer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was fixed by uninstalling and reinstalling QGIS.

Comment: You can set your own answer as answered (the V tick) :)